# Since which Android version is swipe-to-clear supported in notifications?

Tags: android, notifications, sharedpreferences

My app has a preference item which regards what happens when the
user swipes away a notification.

However, I'd like to remove that item if the Android version being
used doesn't support swipe-to-clear notifications (as it makes no
sense to display a useless preference to the user). Thus, I need to
determine at run-time whether it's supported or not.

**Since which API version is this feature included in stock android?**

Answer (score 3):

> I'd like to remove that item if the Android version being used doesn't
>   support swipe-to-clear notifications (as it makes no sense to display
>   a useless preference to the user).

In all previous version of android there is a option to **clear All notification**  ,

if your intention to clear  particular  notification then i am agree with you .

however android  introduce that feature from **Ice Cream Sandwich** version

refer this link for more information http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.0-highlights.html

Answer (score 2):

This feature was included in Android 4.0 ICS API 14.